# My apostrophies look like small boxes

Tags: php

If you go to the page [www.winteradagency.com/mrw/revitalization.php](http://www.winteradagency.com/mrw/revitalization.php) you see that within the text of the document, which is being generated from a database, the apostrophes look like small boxes.  How do I fix that?

Comment: Mojibake! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Answer (score 7):

The issue is character sets and encoding.

The following must have the same encoding:

- The database tables (and columns)
- Your database connection (SET NAMES....)
- Your HTML page

Seeing that your web page is output in UTF-8, either your database tables, or your database connection probably has the wrong encoding (most likely ISO-8859-1).

This is good basic reading on the issue: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 3):

Your encoding is broken. If you switch to ISO-8859-1 in your browser everything looks fine. Either make sure that your text editor saves files as utf-8 or change encoding in the meta tag to iso-8859-1.

Comment: great.  telling me to change the meta tag allowed me to see where that was and once I changed it that fixed it.
you guys are SO smart....THANKS

Comment: Worth every penny you paid us.